# how to activate slider IBAction from cell in TableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, dynamic, slider

My program is creating slider in dynamic cell. I can't just create IBAction using ctrl+"drag and drop" on slider because it is in cell, not in viewController. How can I create this IBAction in ViewController?

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    var gradesNumber: Int?
    var gradeArray: [Grade] = []
    
    @IBOutlet weak var topLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var gradesTableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        gradesTableView.dataSource = self
        for i in 1...gradesNumber! {
            gradeArray.append(Grade(sliderValue: 5, title: "Grade \(i)", grade: "5"))
        }
        gradesTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "ReusableCell")
    }
    
    @IBAction func calculateButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        var avg = 0.0
        for i in gradeArray {
            avg += Double(i.grade)!
        }
        topLabel.text = "Avg: \(avg/Double(gradesNumber!))"
    }
}

extension SecondViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return gradesNumber ?? 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ReusableCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        cell.gradeSlider.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.gradeSlider.setValue(5, animated: true)
        let slider: Grade = gradeArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.gradeValue.text = slider.grade
        cell.gradeNumber.text = slider.title

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Create a custom cell class and have the @IBAction connect to that class.

Answer (score 0):

As Lucas says in his comment, you can create a custom subclass of UITableViewCell and attach the action to the cell class. Then you'd forward the message from the cell to the owning table view. (You'd probably need a delegate property on the cell class so you know who to forward the action to.)

Alternately, you could configure the IBAction in your cellForRowAt method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ReusableCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    //other config code 

    //Make sure the slider doesn't already have the action attached.
    if cell.gradeSlider.actions(forTarget: nil, forControlEvent: .valueChanged) == nil {
         cell.gradeSlider.addTarget(self, action: @selector(actionSelector(:)), controlEvents: .valueChanged]
    }
    return cell
}
```